# Android Shared Preferences alias (key) too long to apply

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, cryptography, sharedpreferences

I'm making custom EncryptedSharedPreferences implementation, and I want to encrypt alias (key) in key/value store so the attacker has a hard time figuring out the values that are stored.

I'm Base64-encoding encrypted bytearray, and when I want to save it, it says that key is too long to have it stored.

Is there a way to shorten Base64 encoding, or to use some other way to make it work? Maybe something like the new EncryptedSharedPreferences from jetpack security library uses, it saves the alias (key) in shorter form, using Tink's deterministic crypto primitives, but how can I achieve that shorter encoding?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: EncryptedSharedPreferences is not fully secure you see original value at device explorer file. for that you have to use AES for encrpt/descrpt and store AES key in Native code like JNI

Comment: Yes, that's the reason I took this custom way, but it's just about that alias key in key/value